# Oracle Service Bus - XML based proxy service

Tags: middleware, osb

I have a xml file like

```
<A>
    <B>abc</B>
    <C>1</C>
</A>
<A>
    <B>def</B>
    <C>2</C>
</A>
```

I have to fetch the value of 'B' based on value of 'C' which will be input of proxy service in OSB.
Please help how i will create this type of proxy service?

Answer (score 1):

An XQuery and 2 simple assigns:

```
Create a XQuery resource which will return your XML structure

1) Inside Proxy, first action is Assign XQuery call to the file above as a local variable, ie: $xmlFile
2) Then another Assign where you do $xmlFile/A[./C=$body/C]/B/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a proxy service without giving any WSDL reference which will accept simple XML as input. OSB wraps this XML input under soap:Body.

So XPath can be used to fetch value from this payload like $body/A[1]/B/text().

Please use Assign action if you have to retrieve only once or else go for Xquery.

Hope it will help.